How to connect genes with lines with ggplot2 in R
I had a data.frame of genes, that I want to plot and connect it with lines
head(df)
      sample       contig  start    end         qseqid  gene       cluster position
1 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 199743 201911 IMEHDJCA_00189 geneE cluster_00365 200827.0
2 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 201914 203275 IMEHDJCA_00190 geneD cluster_01313 202594.5
3 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 203272 205377 IMEHDJCA_00191 geneB cluster_00403 204324.5
4 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 206268 206663 IMEHDJCA_00193 geneC cluster_05858 206465.5
5 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 206686 222306 IMEHDJCA_00194 geneA cluster_00001 214496.0
6 Genome-306 Genome-306_1 287568 289736 DIBHEKPI_00259 geneE cluster_00365 288652.0

so to plot using gggenes geom_gene_arrow
first plot:
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, x = position, y = sample, fill = gene, label = gene)) +
    geom_gene_arrow(arrow_body_height = unit(7, "mm"), 
                    arrowhead_height = unit(7, "mm"), 
                    arrowhead_width = unit(5.7, "mm")) +
    geom_text(angle = 0, hjust = -0.2, size = 4) +
    facet_wrap(~ sample, scales = "free", ncol = 1) + # facet_grid(~ Month, scales = "free", space = "free")
    scale_y_discrete(position="right") +
    scale_fill_discrete(guide="none") + # eliminar las etiquetas del fill, si se quita fill eliminar esta linea 
    gggenes::theme_genes() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white' , color = 'white' ),
          panel.grid.major.y = ggplot2::element_line(colour = "grey", linewidth = 0.6),
          axis.title.y= element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, # sample name size
                                     family="Times New Roman", 
                                     face="bold"),
          plot.margin = unit(c(t=0.3, b=0.3, r=0.3, l=0.001), "mm") ##### posible error 
    )

So, I want to add lines that conect each gene
second plot:
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=position,y=sample)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = gene), color= "grey", linetype="dashed", linewidth=0.3) + #  group = position
    gggenes::geom_gene_arrow(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = sample, fill=gene),
                             arrowhead_width = grid::unit(7, "mm"), 
                             arrowhead_height = grid::unit(7, "mm"), 
                             arrow_body_height = grid::unit(5.7, "mm"), size=0.4 ) + 
    #  facet_wrap(~ sample, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
    scale_y_discrete(position="right") +
    scale_fill_discrete(guide="none") + # eliminar las etiquetas del fill, si se quita fill eliminar esta linea 
    gggenes::theme_genes() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white' , color = 'white' ),
          panel.grid.major.y = ggplot2::element_line(colour = "grey", linewidth = 0.6),
          axis.title.y= element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, # sample name size
                                     family="Times New Roman", 
                                     face="bold"),
          plot.margin = unit(c(t=0.3, b=0.3, r=0.3, l=0.001), "mm") ##### posible error 
    ) 

The problem in my code is, if I use  facet_wrap do not generate the lines, any suggestion ???
I just want all the genes be aligned similar to the first plot and connect the genes with lines similar to second plot !!

If you turn clipping off and create some 'dummy' data you can plot a line from one facet to the other, e.g.
library(tidyverse)
library(gggenes)

df <- read.table(text = "      sample       contig  start    end         qseqid  gene       cluster position
1 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 199743 201911 IMEHDJCA_00189 geneE cluster_00365 200827.0
2 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 201914 203275 IMEHDJCA_00190 geneD cluster_01313 202594.5
3 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 203272 205377 IMEHDJCA_00191 geneB cluster_00403 204324.5
4 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 206268 206663 IMEHDJCA_00193 geneC cluster_05858 206465.5
5 Genome-300 Genome-300_1 206686 222306 IMEHDJCA_00194 geneA cluster_00001 214496.0
6 Genome-306 Genome-306_1 287568 289736 DIBHEKPI_00259 geneE cluster_00365 288652.0")


ggplot(df, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, x = position, y = sample, fill = gene, label = gene)) +
  geom_gene_arrow(arrow_body_height = unit(7, "mm"), 
                  arrowhead_height = unit(7, "mm"), 
                  arrowhead_width = unit(5.7, "mm")) +
  geom_text(angle = 0, hjust = -0.2, size = 4) +
  scale_y_discrete(position="right") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none") +
  gggenes::theme_genes() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white' , color = 'white' ),
        panel.grid.major.y = ggplot2::element_line(colour = "grey", linewidth = 0.6),
        axis.title.y= element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14,
                                   family="Times New Roman", 
                                   face="bold"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(t=0.3, b=0.3, r=0.3, l=0.001), "mm"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ sample, scales = "free", ncol = 1, strip.position = "top") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(sample = "Genome-306"),
               x = df %>% filter(sample == "Genome-306") %>% select(start) %>% min(),
               xend = df %>% filter(sample == "Genome-306") %>% select(end) %>% max(),
               y=1, yend=2.33, inherit.aes = FALSE, lty = 2)


Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0
You'll need to tweak the y positions of the line though, depending on the plotting coordinates of your 'real' data. Is that your intended outcome?

thanks so much, I create a data.frame with a row for each gene, similar to: dm <- data.frame(sample=c("Genome-306", "Genome-306"), x=c(130000, 140000), xend= c(139310, 130000)) and them create the plot: p + geom_segment(data = dm, aes(x=x, xend=xend), y=1, yend=2.23, inherit.aes = FALSE, lty = 2). Is any way to use an other column like dm$gene <- c("geneA", "geneB"), and then indicate to ggplot the way to connect using the column gene, instead of y=1 and yend=2.23 ? thanks so much for the help, it helps me a lot !!!

You're welcome! I'm not sure about your second question - if you make a new post I think someone will come up with a solution - good luck!

You could do this quite easilly using the geneviewer package.
library(geneviewer)
  
GC_chart(
  data,
  start = "start",
  end = "end",
  cluster = "sample",
  group = "gene",
  height = "400px"
) %>%
  GC_links(
    group = "gene",
    value1 = c("geneE"),
    value2 = c("geneE"),
    curve = FALSE,
    linkStyle =
      list(
        fill = "#FFF",
        strokeWidth = 2,
        stroke = "black",
        strokeDasharray = "5"
      )
  ) %>%
  GC_legend(FALSE) %>%
  GC_scale(cluster = 1) %>%
  GC_labels()


